# Showing a shadow on a transparent floor/plane in scenekit

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, scenekit, metal

trying to figure out how I can render a shadow on an invisible plane, so the background of my `sceneView` shows through.

THREE.js has a `ShadowMaterial` which does exactly this - only the shadow is rendered.

Current thinking is to make a custom Metal shader which looks straightforward, but i'm unsure how to go about knocking out the floor to show everything aside from the shadow.

Here's an example of a shadow catcher: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Maya-2015-Shadow-Catching-with-Use-Background-material.html

Comment: What kind of shadows are you using?  Shadow mapping, shadow volumes?  Also, are you currently able to draw over your `sceneView` 3d objects?

Comment: dyanmic shadows using the ambient and spotlight `SNNodes`, unsure what apple is doing under the hood. I am able to place `UIView`s over my SceneKit view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so check out this example project on Github:

https://github.com/carolight/Metal-Shadow-Map/blob/master/Shadows/Shader.metal#L67

That link is to the shader that performs the shadow map testing.  Basically, it normalizes the Z position of the fragment being rendered and compares it to the Z-Buffer of the shadow map.  If it is less than the shadow-Z, the pixel is fully lit (line 67) else it is tinted slightly (line 69).

What you want to do instead is write (0,0,0, shadow_opacity) for line 69 and (0,0,0,0) for line 67.  This should emit transparent pixels. Set shadow_opacity as a uniform from [0.0..1.0].

The rest of the setup is shown in the [example](https://github.com/carolight/Metal-Shadow-Map/blob/master/Shadows/Renderer.swift).  Tilt the plane/camera to the desired setting, skip drawing the cube/vase/whatever in the `main pass` if you don't really want it in the scene (line [279](https://github.com/carolight/Metal-Shadow-Map/blob/master/Shadows/Renderer.swift#L279)).  (However, note the `shadow pass` and keep it there).